# List computers on VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, remote-desktop

I'm on a mac computer working at home. I'm connected to work network via VPN. Can I some how list computers on this network. I need this to find my computer at the office and connect to it via RDP.

Comment: How critical is it that you connect remotely before you next visit the office?

Comment: @wrecclesham this is not that critical, but it'll be great to know how to do this in case this situation happens again. VPN grands me access everywhere I need, git, jira, etc, but this time I need some local files from machine itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely can't (I say likely because its a bit dependent on your VPN setup - it is conceivable something is being done in the background to map things - but its not a widely standardised mechanism)

You can get a port scanner and scan everything in the appropriate range to see what is open on port 3389 and 3390 - and then try and connect - BUT GET THE OK FROM MANAGEMENT or IT FIRST, as this could be considered hacking.